when I try to install (edgeR) by Bioconductor, having problems with "'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories
I am using this to install edgeR package-
BiocManager::install("edgeR")

it is showing
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard
repositories, see 'help("repositories", package =
"BiocManager")' for details.
Replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/
Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection

I am using R version R-4.3.3. How to solve this issue?
Thank you in advance
I have tried to change the CRAN,but it didn't work

Those warnings look ominous, but reading the help("repositories", package = "BiocManager"), we see an opportunity to chooseBioCmirror, which you attempted to do via CRAN. In a session
>chooseBioCmirror()# <return>
Secure BioC mirrors 

 1: 0-Bioconductor (World-wide) [https]
 2: Germany (Gottingen) [https]
 3: Japan (Wako) [https]
 4: China (Peking) [https]
 5: China (Nanjing) [https]
 6: China (Hefei Anhui) [https]
 7: Norway (Bergen) [https]
 8: Denmark (Aalborg) [https]
 9: Sweden (Umea) [https]
10: (other mirrors)

Selection: 1 # <return>
>

should work. Report if not.
